# Tricky issue with getting a bouncing effect on a specific class or div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help since I am trying to make my left control bounce.

On my website I have a music player which is linked to two controls, previous and next. I want both controls to bounce when the user clicks on it. Now I have Jquery and Jquery Yui applied to the website and a simple javascript function which seems to work, but somehow not when I specify the controls.

This is the code:

```
$(function(){

    //Add bounce effect on Click of the DIV
    $('.jp-prev').click(function () {
          $(this).effect("bounce", { times:5 }, 300);
    });

    $('#bouncy2').click(function () {
          $(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'left', times:5 }, 300);
    });

    $('#bouncy3').click(function () {
          $(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'right', times:5 }, 300);
    });

    $('#bouncy4').click(function () {
          $(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'down', times:5 }, 300);
    });

    //Bounce all DIVs on click of button
    $("#bounceAll").click(function(){
        $("div").click();
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
        <div id="jp_interface_1" class="jp-interface">
    .       <ul class="jp-controls">
                   <li><a href="#" class="jp-play"></a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause"></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="jp-prev"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="jp-next"></a></li>
                <li><a href="audio_samples.php" class="jp-more-songs">Listen to more Audio Samples</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="jp-progress">
                 <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                 <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                  </div>
             </div>
             <div class="jp-title"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just found out that the javascript cant handle a class that is applied to a link or anchor. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have a click event assigned to #bounceAll, but there's no element with that id in your html code. Same with #bouncy2-4. Do these exist on the page? Also this: **$("div").click();** is a bad idea. You are firing a click even from every div on your page with that. Please go into more detail about what you mean when you say 'specify my controls' or post all your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ if you can

Comment: Ok changed it now. The part of the javascript active for testing is only bouncy , now renamed to jp-prev). I want jp-prev to bounce when the user clicks on the div but somehow the javascript code does not find the div or it just doesnt fire because it has a anchor tag assigned to it. What should I do?

Comment: Your jp-prev anchor tag is empty though. There's nothing in it, so what are you expecting a user to click on or what are you expecting to bounce? Is it being defined in the stylesheet? You should really post all the code you have available and an example on jsfiddle.net if you can. And you're still firing a click even on every div click, that's going to cause tons of problems and you need to get rid of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put jquery before your code and it might work

Comment: Thanks it works just like you said. I didnt have jquery in my head section